# Commit manually in django

Tags: python, django

Is there a better way to do the following in a django Model method? The following looks quite verbose, as I could do the same in the SQL shell with one line:

```
class ItemMaster(models.Model):
    ...

    @classmethod
    @transaction.commit_manually
    def update_imdb_rank(self):
        '''
        Update all ranks from the IMDbEntry table
        '''
        cursor = connection.cursor()
        cursor.execute("UPDATE main_itemmaster i JOIN mturk_imdbentry m USING (imdb_url) SET i.imdb_rank=m.imdb_rank")
        transaction.commit()
```

Comment: Do you have a foreign key from main.ItemMaster to mturk.IMDBEntry or vice versa? And is it based on ```imdb_url```?

Comment: There's not a foreign key on either, they'll just be the same.

Comment: Is there a reason not to use the ORM to do the update?

Comment: If you were hoping to use the ORM, then you won't be able to unless you add a FK or a generic foreign key relationship between the two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `with` statement to reduce verbosity if you wish:

```
class ItemMaster(models.Model):
    ...

    @classmethod
    def update_imdb_rank(self):
        with transaction.atomic():
            cursor = connection.cursor()
            cursor.execute("UPDATE main_itemmaster i JOIN mturk_imdbentry m USING (imdb_url) SET i.imdb_rank=m.imdb_rank")
```